# From VB to C#. Some specific

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, translate

I have no experience with VB, but I need to convert a script from Visual Basic to C#. And I have some questions

1. Every method start with some `ByVal` things like

   `ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs`

I can't find any way to write this in C#.

2. The `Dim` statement. I just can't understand this and the way i must convert it to C#. 
   Example:

   `Dim drRcp As SqlClient.SqlDataReader`

   `Dim Apt_Id As String = clsShared.ReadSetting("LAST_RECORD")`
3. Is there any program, website or something that convert parts of a code between languages?

Comment: You can use convertor : http://converter.telerik.com/

Comment: http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/vbnet_csharp_comparison.html

Comment: Although that is a fine tool, it cannot fully convert VB.Net to C# and vice-versa. For instance, accessing array members in VB.Net is done by placing element index in parentheses. But in C# it must be placed in brackets. That tool cannot automate this(from personal experience).

Answer (score 2):

This is quite basic stuff, you should be able to read up on it all over the web. But here goes:

1. In C# you don't use ByVal. The example would like this in C#:

   (Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
2. The declaration syntax is also different, like this:

   SqlClient.SqlDatareader drRcp;

   string Apt_Id = clsShared.ReadSetting("LAST_RECORD");
3. Yes, as mentioned by Abdellah OUMGHAR above, converter.telerik.com ought to do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use Telerik code converter and sometimes need to make manual corrections.

Other than that converting VB code is not very hard, provided the coder used .Net classes vs old VB libraries and commands.

For example, dim is for defining a var (and also you might use "var" keyword where appropriate).

```
Dim drRcp As SqlClient.SqlDataReader 
Dim Apt_Id As String = clsShared.ReadSetting("LAST_RECORD")
```

translates as:

```
SqlClient.SqlDataReader drRcp;  
string Apt_Id = clsShared.ReadSetting("LAST_RECORD");
```

Comment: Yes, that converter is a good place to go, but it does not always produce ideal code so it needs to be modified after the convert. Still a great place to start and a great response.

Answer (score 0):

1. ByVal is specifying to pass the parameter By Value, which is the default in VB.net and C# and doesn't need to be included.
2. VB.net variable declaration is `Dim varName As Type`, C# is `Type varName`. Both can also determine type themselves given a definition but should be avoid when possible; readability/maintainable practices; `Dim varName = "string value"` vs. `var varName = "string"` in C#.
3. See Comments on question.

Answer (score 0):

ByVal of VB means passby value which is by default.
        Pass By Value : function add(int a,int b)-- both a and b is Pass By Value  -- While  function add(ref int a,ref int b) is pass by reference
1. so  (ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) = (Object sender,EventArgs e)

2. Dim drRcp As SqlClient.SqlDataReader Dim Apt_Id As String = clsShared.ReadSetting("LAST_RECORD")  == SqlClient.SqlDataReader drRcp=new SqlClient.SqlDataReader()
   string Apt_id=clsShared.ReadSetting("LAST_RECORD")
3. Go to google and type Convert Vb.net to c#. You will get scores of online converted.